# CKEditor resizing tabs in dialogs

Tags: ckeditor

So I removed a bunch of buttons in the table info dialogs. There are only 5 buttons left, so it feels pretty empty with the default size.

Here are the codes:

```
CKEDITOR.on( 'dialogDefinition', function( ev ) {
        var dialogName = ev.data.name;
        var dialogDefinition = ev.data.definition;
        if(dialogName == 'table' || dialogName == 'tableProperties'){
            var advTab = dialogDefinition.getContents('advanced');
            var infoTab = dialogDefinition.getContents('info');
            var advClass = advTab.get('advCSSClasses');
            var cmbAlignBut = infoTab.get('cmbAlign');

            infoTab.remove('txtSummary');
            infoTab.remove('txtCaption');
            infoTab.remove('selBorder');
            infoTab.remove('txtCellSpace');
            infoTab.remove('txtCellPad');
            infoTab.remove('selHeaders');
            infoTab.remove('cmbAlign');
            infoTab.remove('txtBorder');

            advClass.type = "select";
            advClass.requiredContent = "table(cke-xyz)";
            advClass.label = "Table Type";
            advClass.default = "normal-table";
            advClass.items = [
                ["Normal", "normal-table"],
                ["Comparison", "comparison-table"],
                ["Links", "link-table"]
            ];

            infoTab.add(advClass);

            dialogDefinition.removeContents('advanced');
            console.log(advClass);
            console.log(cmbAlignBut);
        }
    });
```

And here's how it looks like:

[image: And here's how it looks like:]

How do I resize at least the height?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see: https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor-dev/blob/master/plugins/table/dialogs/table.js#L60
Dialogs usually have `minHeight` assigned. If you wish to change it, please use :

```
CKEDITOR.on( 'dialogDefinition', function( ev ) {
  var dialogName = ev.data.name;
  var dialogDefinition = ev.data.definition;
  if(dialogName == 'table' || dialogName == 'tableProperties'){
    ev.data.definition.minHeight = 120; // you can also use ev.data.definition.minHeight = 0;
    ...
```